# Multiplicative subgroup of a finite field with prescribed trace.

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum, additive-combinatorics

Any suggestions/methods/estimates for the following problem would be very appreciated.

$l,p$ are primes with $p \equiv 1 \!\! \pmod l$. $r$ is a positive integer with $r \equiv 1 \!\! \pmod p$ and $q = p^r$. $Tr$ is the field trace $\mathbb{F}_q \to \mathbb{F}_p$, so $Tr(x) = x + x^p + \cdots + x^{p^{r-1}}$. Note that $Tr\,|_{\mathbb{F}_p} = \text{id}$.

Finally $H = H_1$ is the subgroup of order $l$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ and $H_r$ is the largest subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$ such that $H \subset H_r$ and $Tr(H_r) \subset H$.

> **Questions around $H_r$:** How big is $H_r$? Or, varying $r$, how big can $H_r$ be made relative to $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$? Can anything be said about the size of the fibers of $Tr: H_r \to H$? Can they be made to have the same size?

(The idea behind this is that I'd like to be able to compare an exponential sum over $H$ with one over $H_r$.)

(Note that $H_r = H + K_r$ for some subset $K_r$ of $\ker Tr = \{ x \in \mathbb{F}_q \: | \: Tr(x) = 0$}.)

Comment: A cool question! Initially I wanted to ask about how you deal with the need to have $Tr(\overline{1})=\overline{r}\in H_1$, but then I read the question more carefully :-)

Comment: Thanks, Jyrki! I'm hoping to do something cool(er) with it in proving an equidistribution result. I have small exponential sum over $\mathbb{F}_p$ that I'm hoping to relate to a larger sum over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Good bounds only seem available to larger sums, in general.